# F5 fails to launch Azure function project locally in VSCode

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm on WSL oh-my-zsh Ubuntu 18.04. I was following this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/functions-extension/run-app) and pressed F5 to launch Azure function locally but I ran into this error in my terminal:

```
> Executing task: func extensions install <

/bin/bash: /d: No such file or directory
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

FWIW, I have verified Azure function installation with `sudo func`.

Comment: Have you installed git and [.NET Core 2.1 for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#linux)?

Comment: @JerryLiu yes I have

Comment: Do you create function somewhere like `/d`? Pay attention to the permission and also we need to install nodejs to debug a js function.